# Are there mechanical differences between a mule and a donkey?

Tags: dnd-5e, mount

In the PHB, the list of available mounts includes donkeys & mules, both having the same buying price, speed and carrying weight.

I know that, in real life, mules and donkeys have differences (after all, a mule is half-horse !), but I could only find game statistics on mules, not donkeys, for 5E.

I want my next character to start off with a donkey, but I don't know if I should simply use a mule's statistics to represent it or not.

Are there mechanical differences between a mule and a donkey in 5E ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that NSFW covers the mechanical differences.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are not any differences as written. Using the mule statistics for donkeys seems reasonable enough, given that D&D isn't really meant to finely model the abilities of real-world creatures (and they mostly have statistics *at all* simply for the case of fighting 'em). The Monster Manual (appendix A) says:

> OTHER ANIMALS
>
> A book of this size can’t contain statistics for every animal inhabiting your D&D campaign world. However, you can use the stat block of one animal to represent another easily enough. For example, you can use the panther statistics to represent a jaguar, the giant goat statistics to represent a buffalo, and the hawk statistics to represent a falcon.

The difference between "giant goat" and "buffalo" probably exceeds that of mule to donkey.

If this doesn't feel satisfying, though, I think it's reasonable to work with your DM to modify to taste. As long as you're not giving it a +10 2d12 gore attack and firebreathing, I can't see why anyone would really make a fuss.

(If you do want to make your own, my offhand thoughts: Remove the Beast of Burden feature, drop its strength and raise its dexterity, and drop its attack damage too. Maybe give it more charisma, because those ears are so cute.)

Comment: "What do you mean my 8gp mule can't breath fire and gore those orcs? What did I bother paying for?!"

Comment: @mattdm Forgot the "Stubborn" feature for the mule. Recharge 1-2; The mule will simply oppose whatever it is that the handler wants to do for 1d6 minutes.

Comment: Ear cuteness is an important but vastly underutilized game statistic. +1 for including it @mattdm

Comment: @mattdm, don't forget rats and mice in additon to your 'giant goat' and 'buffalo'.